# Numerical optimization and minimization

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, numerical

Lets say I have a reference node R and several test nodes T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>.... T<sub>n</sub>.
Any particular node has a set of properties Rp<sub>1</sub>, Rp<sub>2</sub>, ... Rp<sub>n</sub> and T<sub>1</sub>p<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>, T<sub>1</sub>p<sub>3</sub>, ... T<sub>1</sub>p<sub>n</sub>, and T<sub>2</sub>p<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>p<sub>2</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>p<sub>3</sub>, ... T<sub>2</sub>p<sub>n</sub>, and so on. So, any node can have n properties, each of a particular type.

I have my own method of defining the distance between any two properties of the same kind between any two nodes. Furthermore, I would weigh the distances between properties and then sum them up. Thus, the distance between R and T<sub>1</sub> would be:

> dRT<sub>1</sub> = w<sub>1</sub>*dRT<sub>1</sub>p<sub>1</sub> + w<sub>2</sub>*dRT<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub> + w<sub>3</sub>*dRT<sub>1</sub>p<sub>3</sub> + w<sub>4</sub>*dRT<sub>1</sub>p<sub>4</sub> + ... w<sub>n</sub>*dRT<sub>1</sub>p<sub>n</sub>.

Now, given the reference node R, and the test nodes T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub> .... T<sub>n</sub>, and given that I know the distance is the least between R and a particular node T<sub>m</sub> (1<m<n), and if the weights are actually variables and the distances are actually constants, how do I calculate the weights such that dRTm is the minimal among all the distances between R and every other test nodes.

We have the distances dRT<sub>1</sub>, dRT<sub>2</sub>, dRT<sub>3</sub>, dRT<sub>4</sub>, ... dRT<sub>n</sub> and we know that dRT<sub>m</sub> is minimum. What algorithm should we use to determine the weights?

Comment: Are all the dRT_i positive? If so, is anything preventing you from choosing w_i such that dRT_m is equal to zero?

Comment: Yes, the distance between the properties of the same kind between any two nodes is positive. Yes, the final distance between two nodes is also positive. How do I choose w_i such that the final distance is zero?

Comment: The trivial way is to set all weights equal to zero. I'm guessing that's not what you intended. Are there any restrictions on the weights (e.g.: maybe all weights > 0)?

Comment: The weights cannot be set to zero. If the weights are set to zero, then all the other distances are also zero. But yes, all weights should be greater than 0.

Comment: Then, it is not always the case that you can force dRT_m to be minimum. Consider the following: dRT_1 = (1,1,1), dRT_2 = (10,10,10). There is no way to make dRT_2 the minimum. You will likely need some more structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression, where after the article says "Thus the model takes the form" y is dRt1, the x variables are e.g. dRT1p1, and the beta variables they are trying to work out - their parameter vector - is your w1, w2...

Comment: Thanks. I saw the link, but there the output variable y is known. In my case, dRT1 is not known. All I know is dRTm should be the minimum, and I know m.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want to do is to set the weights so that a particular distance (dRTm) gets a lower numerical value than any other distance, i.e. set the weights so that the inequalities

```
dRTm <= dRT1
...
dRTm <= dRTn
```

are all fulfilled. Setting all the weights to zero as mentioned in one of the comments is a trivial solution because all distances will be identically zero and all the inequalities trivially fulfilled (with equality replacing inequality) so it makes more sense to consider the stronger problem

```
dRTm < dRT1
...
dRTm < dRT(m-1)
dRTm < dRT(m+1)
...
dRTm < dRTn
```

In any case, this a simple **[linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)** problem. Put in the above constraints and then minimize

```
min : dRTm
```

It is linear because the calculated individual distances are constants at the time of solving for minimum dRTm. You can solve this with any [linear programming package](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), or if you want to cook up a slow but easy to implement solution by yourself, e.g. with [Fourier-Motzkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination) elimination. [Simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) would be the actual method of choice, however.